# Response is null while deploying to vercel in my Next.js 13 app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to deploy my Next.js 13 app with typescript and firebase in vercel but it gives me some errors:

[issue while deploying to vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2KKv.png)

```
import { db } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { DocumentData, addDoc, collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";


export async function GET() {
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "blogs"));
        const tempData: DocumentData[] = []
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            tempData.push({id: doc.id,...doc.data()})
        });
        return NextResponse.json({message:'success',status: 200, data: tempData})

    } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json({error: `${error}`});
    }
}

export async function POST(req: NextRequest, res:NextResponse) {
    try {
        const res = await req.json();
        if (res === null) return 'response is null';
        const title = res?.title as string;
        const user_id = res?.user_id as string;
        const thumbnail = res?.thumbnail as string;
        const category = res?.category as string;
        const blogContent = res?.blogContent as string;
        const isPosted = res?.isPosted ?? false;
        const author = res?.author as string;

        // Check if it's a new blog or an update
        const isNewBlog = req.method === 'POST';

        let created_at;
        let updated_at;

        if (isNewBlog) {
            // For a new blog, set created_at to the current timestamp
            created_at = new Date();
            updated_at = new Date();
        } else {
            // For an update, only update updated_at
            updated_at = new Date();
        }

        // Generate the slug from the title
        const slug = title?.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/g, '-');
        const postData = { title, slug, blogContent, category, thumbnail, user_id, author, created_at, updated_at, isPosted }
        await addDoc(collection(db, "blogs"), postData);

        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'successfully added a blog!', status: 200, data: postData });

    } catch (error: any) {
        return NextResponse.json({error: `${error}`});
    }
}
```

I tried to deploy the app and expect NextResponse type but error says type must be whithin Response, void or Promise<void | Response> but Next.js 13 is all about NextReponse

Comment: Your usage is inconsistent. [Route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers) accept a `Request` / `NextRequest` parameter and **return** a response value